# In Fighting Fantasy books, what is considered “one item”?

Tags: books, games, fighting-fantasy

Step 313 in The Warlock of Firetop Mountain says, in part:

> He wears a suit of leather armor no better than your own, holds a wooden
> shield on one wrist and clutches a steel-bladed sword in his other hand.
> In his pockets are 8 Gold Pieces and around his neck is a silver crucifix.
>
> You may take any two of these items you wish.

Are the gold pieces collectively one item (i.e., I could take the gold pieces and something else)? Or if I take the crucifix, does that mean I can only take 1 gold piece? I would assume the latter, but then I don't see the point of being told he has 8 gold pieces if I could never take more than two anyways.

Note: I first tried this question over at [rpg.stackexchange.com](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100107/in-fighting-fantasy-books-what-is-considered-one-item) but they said it was off-topic and they sent me here. I expect, however, that the best answer will come from someone who is quite familiar with role-playing-game customs, rather than someone who is just familiar with Sci Fi tropes.

Comment: There was a video game adaptation. Would you accept an answer from how they interpret it?

Comment: I'm at loss as to why people over at RPG would see this off-topic. Isn't your question about a manual for a game?

Comment: It's a CYOA solo adventure. You can read the comment thread to see their logic. I don't agree with it.

Comment: @Gallifreyan RPG.SE's leading policy position is currently that Choose Your Own Adventure books are off topic on RPG.SE, but that's in debate right now on our meta.

Comment: @Doppelgreener - They're firmly on-topic here. Send 'em over!

Comment: First time I see in a gamebook that gold is actually an item.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The full text of that last sentence is

> You may take any two of these items you wish. Write them on your Equipment List and turn to 221. Also add 1 luck and 1 skill point.

Looking at the text of Step 221, The 8 gold pieces are all one item.

> **221**
>   What are these mysterious items you have collected? Which have you written down first on your Equipment List:
>
> The armour?
>   Turn to 72
>
> The shield?
>   Turn to 132
>
> The sword?
>   Turn to 27
>
> *The gold?*
>   Turn to 110
>
> The crucifix?
>   Turn to 170

Images of the steps from the book:
[image: Step 313] [image: Step 221]

Answer (score 10):

**Gold isn't (normally) considered an item.** You can collect it whenever you encounter it and spend it (and subdivide it) however you want. It's recorded in a distinct box on your adventure sheet.

[image]

As has been pointed out, in this *particular* case it's treated as an item but really shouldn't be.

> **110:** You are now 8 Gold Pieces richer. You also find another 2 Gold
>   Pieces in his boot, hidden there for safety. Turn to 91. Record the
>   Gold on your Adventure Sheet.

Comment: +1 for the hand-drawn red circle. -1 for that the actual gamebook does treat it as an item for this. :) Although, if you follow to 110, you simply add that gold to your total (and add 2 more).